# How to derive scanr f a = map ( foldr f a ) . tails in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm taking a course on Haskell and this is one of my assignments. I'm completely clueless as to how to even begin solving this. I'd appreciate if someone pointed me in the right direction. I have "Introduction to Functional Programming using Haskell" by Bird and Wadler.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact answer depends on how `scanr` was defined. Surely if `scanr` is defined exactly as your equation states, then the goal becomes trivial ;-)

As a general advice, I would start by eta-expanding the question. That is, we prove the goal by establishing that

```
scanr f a l = (map (foldr f a) . tails) l
```

for all `f,a,l`. Then I would try to proceed by induction on the list argument `l` (i.e., on its length).

Case nil: If `l` is `[]` then the equation holds because ...

Case cons: Assume the equation holds for `l`. Then the equation must hold for `x:l` because ...

Here equational reasoning should suffice: by expanding the (recursive) definitions of `scanr`,`map`,`foldr`,`tails` you should be able to conclude.

Comment: This question should be closed as stupid. I was very new to haskell when I posted it and I actually misinterpreted what was required of me... Your answer is correct, all that is required to derive this relationship is a simple inductive reasoning (we were even given an inductive proof for a something similar - with foldl instead of foldr). Shame that my very first question on stackoverflow was so silly ;)